# Redux store is a step behind when using a function

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, graphql

I have an application that has a book review functionality. I'm using google books api. The addReview function is basically broken into two parts. The first one adds a book to my backend, and the other adds the review for that book when you click "add review" button. It also checks if the book is already in the backend through the book_api_id from google api. I have this functionality working already. My only issue is that in add book function, I can't get that newly created book id right away. so it errors because my review relies on the book_id (different from book_api_id) to correlate the review.

My issue right now is if I create a review from a clean slate (clearing local storage and the redux-persist and starting a new localhost:3000 app, when I add a book review for a nonexisting book, it would add the book but then throw an error that the book_id for review is null but in redux store's next state, it shows that book_id.

How do I get that value before hitting add review?

I've tried wrapping my redux function with try catch, but I'm not getting anywhere. Currently a lot of my function is using Async-Await which works perfectly in terms of checking if a book exist, then if the book exist, to use that id. I know it's an async function because doing some research, the redux next state is basically queued in that function.

```
    This is part of a bigger code, but it's an else block in a function so think of this as: 
 How can I use next state right away in the same function? 

 else {
    props.addBook(bookInfo)
    let newId = parseInt(props.bookId) // this id is from the redux store
    if (values.rating && values.review){
      let newBookReview = {
        book_id: newId,
        user_id: props.currentUser.id,
        rating: parseFloat(values.rating),
        content: values.review
      }
      props.addReview(newBookReview); // this is the add review function 

  } // end of else

     // My add book function (this uses graphQL) from book_action file
     export function addBook(book){
      return dispatch => {
       dispatch({type: ADDING_BOOK});
       const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
       const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: "http://localhost:9090",
        headers: { authorization: token }
       });
       client
        .mutate({
          mutation: ADD_BOOK_MUTATION,
          variables: {
          input: book
        }
      })
     .then(response => {
        dispatch({
         type: BOOK_ADDED,
         payload: response.data.addBook //this payload contains the bookid
         })
      })
     .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
         type: BOOK_ERROR,
         payload: "Unable to add book"
        })
     })
    }
    }

  // My add review function from my review_action file. 

     export function addReview(review){
        return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: ADDING_REVIEW});
       const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
       const client = new ApolloClient({
         uri: "http://localhost:9090",
         headers: { authorization: token }
        });
        client
        .mutate({
          mutation: ADD_REVIEW_MUTATION,
          variables: {
            input: review
          }
         })
         .then(response => {
           console.log('success', response)
           dispatch({
           type: REVIEW_ADDED,
           payload: response.data.addReview
         })
        })
       .catch(error => {
        console.log('review error',error)
        dispatch({
          type: REVIEW_ERROR,
          payload: "Unable to add a review"
           })
         })
          }
       }
```

What I'm getting is a null value but in next state from redux-logger, it shows the book data where I can get Id.

My error is that addReview fails because at the current redux state, book is null.

Answer (score 0):

> Redux store is a step behind when using a function

This is an expected behaviour. The store will be updated every dispatch via reducers. But this update is used for the next render.

Keeping this in mind, the best way is just do a refactor:

1. Pass values as payload

```
export function addBook(book){
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADDING_BOOK,
      payload: book,
    });
  }
}

export function addReview(review){
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADDING_REVIEW,
      payload: review,
    });
  }
}
```

2. Listen for component updates via `connect` then do a mutation

```
mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { book } = state;

  return {
    book,
  }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // only do a review if a book is already available
  if (!prevProps.book && this.props.book) {
    // do a review mutation
    // client.mutate(...)
  }
}
```

**Using Redux Saga**

You can also use [redux-saga](/questions/tagged/redux-saga). Add watchers for `ADDING_BOOK` and `ADDING_REVIEW` action to do a mutation. This way, the store is updated first via reducers then control is back to the saga.

```
function* root() {
  yield takeEvery(ADDING_BOOK, watchAddBook);
  yield takeEvery(ADDING_REVIEW, watchAddReview);
}

function* watchAddBook(action) {
  const { payload } = action; // book payload

  // client.mutate(...)
}

function* watchAddReview(action) {
  const { payload } = action; // review payload

  // client.mutate(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was limited because of how redux is set. I'll keep in mind using componentDidUpdate like you mentioned in the future. I got mine to work by adding the book, then using a function to search the database for the book_id using the book_api_id. and then using that value as the review value. Seems to work properly. Not sure what the technical debt is for doing what I did but it's working pretty smoothly.